# pipeline en un jenkins dockerizado

Tags: docker, jenkins, pipeline, docker-machine

Tengo una máquina Linux que se supone tiene el cauce abierto a internet (con el proxy autentificado) tiene instalado docker y un contenedor con jenkins basado en Debian 11 bulleye, pues bien le configuro en al archivo /etc/environment y el /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00proxy con los valores para salir por el proxy y evidentemente en la configuración de los plugins en el frontend de jenkins hago lo mismo pero me da error, no se instalan la mayoría de los plugins. Mi duda es la siguiente, si está todo bien podría ser que la red que crea Docker para los contenedores la detecte el proxy y las ip que pertenecen a esa red al no estar en su tabla de accesos corte la comunicación, estoy elucubrando pero ¿alguien tiene alguna idea? Y que sea buena, jajajaja.

Un saludo.